# Kivy MD Helper Text

Tags: python, user-interface, kivy, kivymd

I'm trying to add in a helper text in Kivy Md which pops up if an invalid password is entered. However the helper text that I use is quite long and therefore doesn't fit. Does anyone know how I can move it or make it fit somehow. Below is an image of my issue:

- [image: text that doesn't fit]

Below is the relevant section of code:

```
    def AddToRecord(self, email, passw, name, cpass):
            email.error = False
            passw.error = False
            name.error = False
            cpass.error = False

            NewEmail = email.text
            NewName  = name.text
            NewPassword = passw.text
            ConfirmPassword = cpass.text
            if  len(NewName) and len(NewEmail) and len(NewPassword) and len(ConfirmPassword)> 0:
                if (len(NewPassword)>8 and any(char in (set(string.punctuation)) for char in (NewPassword)) and
                        any(char in (set(string.punctuation)) for char in (NewPassword)) and
                        any(char in (set(string.ascii_uppercase)) for char in (NewPassword)) and
                        any(char in (set(string.ascii_lowercase)) for char in (NewPassword)) and
                        any(char in (set(string.digits)) for char in (NewPassword))):
                    if NewPassword == ConfirmPassword:
                        # Connect to or create a new database
                        conn = sqlite3.connect('UserRecords.db')
                        # Create a cursor object to execute SQL commands
                        cursor = conn.cursor()
                        # Create a table to store the records
                        cursor.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (name TEXT, email TEXT, password TEXT)''')
                        # Insert the user's information into the table
                        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO users (name, email, password) VALUES (?, ?, ?)", (NewName, NewEmail, NewPassword))
                        # Committing the changes and closing the connection to the database file
                        conn.commit()
                        conn.close()
                    else:
                        cpass.helper_text = "The passwords you have entered do not match"
                        cpass.error = True
                else:
                    passw.helper_text = """Your password needs to be a minium of 8 characters and must 
                    contain a number, lowercase letter, upper case letter and special character (@!#$, ETC)"""
                    passw.error = True
            else:
                if len(NewName) <1  and len(NewEmail) >0:
                    name.error = True
                elif len(NewPassword) <1 and len(NewEmail) >0:
                    passw.helper_text = "This is a required feild"
                    passw.error = True
                elif len(ConfirmPassword) <1 and len(NewEmail) >0:
                    cpass.helper_text = "This is required field"
                    cpass.error = True
```

Below is the relevant section of KV file:

```
<SignupScreen>:
    ScrollView:
        FloatLayout:
            size_hint: (1, 1.3)

            MDIconButton:
                icon: "keyboard-backspace"
                pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.35, "center_y": 0.97}
                on_release:
                    root.manager.current = "menu"

            Image:
                source: "Images/RegisterImage.png"
                size_hint_x: 0.4
                size_hint_y: 0.75
                allow_stretch: True
                pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.75}

            MDLabel:
                text: "Sign up"
                halign: "center"
                pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.387, "center_y": 0.54}
                font_size: 30
                font_style: "H5"

            EmailField:
                id: email_widget
                hint_text: "Email"
                pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.48}
                size_hint_x: None
                width: "250dp"

            NameField:
                id: name_widget
                hint_text: "Name"
                pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.39}
                size_hint_x: None
                width: "250dp"

            PasswordField:
                id: passw_widget
                size_hint_x: None
                width: "250dp"
                hint_text: "Password"
                pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.3}

            ConfirmPasswordField:
                id: cpass_widget
                size_hint_x: None
                width: "250dp"
                hint_text: "Confirm Password"
                pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.21}


            MDFillRoundFlatButton:
                text: "Sign up"
                pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.12}
                md_bg_color: 0.3607, 0.3882, 1
                size_hint: 0.3, 0
                on_release:
                    app.AddToRecord(root.ids.email_widget.ids.email_field, root.ids.passw_widget.ids.text_field, root.ids.name_widget.ids.name_field,
                    root.ids.cpass_widget.ids.text_field)

            MDLabel:
                text: "by continuing you agree to the"
                font_size: 15
                halign: 'center'
                pos_hint: {"center_y": 0.08}

            MDTextButton:
                text: "Terms and Conditions"
                font_size: 15
                pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.066}
                theme_text_color: "Custom"
                text_color: 0.3607, 0.3882, 1

#Custom buttons and text fields are located below

<PasswordField>:
    size_hint_y: None
    height: text_field.height

    MDTextField:
        id: text_field
        hint_text: root.hint_text
        text: root.text
        password: True
        icon_left: "lock"
        ##need to try and fix this helper text, attempt below. It is labeled attempt 1
        helper_text: "Your password needs to be a minium of 8 characters and must contain a number, lowercase letter, upper case letter and special character (@!#$, ETC)"
        helper_text_mode: "on_error"

    MDIconButton:
        icon: "eye-off"
        pos_hint: {"center_y": .5}
        pos: text_field.width - self.width + dp(8), 0
        theme_text_color: "Hint"
        on_release:
            self.icon = "eye" if self.icon == "eye-off" else "eye-off"
            text_field.password = False if text_field.password is True else True

##this label needs to be fixed or alternative solution's - attempt 1
    #MDLabel:
        #id: passw_helper
        #text: ""
        #font_size: 20
        #halign: 'left'
        #pos_hint: {"center_y": -0.1}

<ConfirmPasswordField>:
    size_hint_y: None
    height: text_field.height

    MDTextField:
        id: text_field
        hint_text: root.hint_text
        text: root.text
        password: True
        icon_left: "lock"
        helper_text: ""
        helper_text_mode: "on_error"

    MDIconButton:
        icon: "eye-off"
        pos_hint: {"center_y": .5}
        pos: text_field.width - self.width + dp(8), 0
        theme_text_color: "Hint"
        on_release:
            self.icon = "eye" if self.icon == "eye-off" else "eye-off"
            text_field.password = False if text_field.password is True else True

<EmailField>:
    size_hint_y: None
    height: email_field.height

    MDTextField:
        id: email_field
        hint_text: root.hint_text
        text: root.text
        icon_left: "email"
        helper_text: "Please enter a valid email"
        validator: "email"
        helper_text_mode: "on_error"

<NameField>:
    size_hint_y: None
    height: name_field.height

    MDTextField:
        id: name_field
        hint_text: root.hint_text
        text: root.text
        icon_left: "account"
        helper_text: "This is a required field"
        helper_text_mode: "on_error"
```

Any help is much appreicated!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding line breaks in your error string.  This way will you can control how the line wraps.
ie.

```
helper_text: "Your password needs to be a minium of 8 characters \nand must contain a number, lowercase letter, upper case \nletter and special character (@!#$, ETC)"
        helper_text_mode: "on_error"
```

This still won't fit inside the box but at least it will look better.